# Creating a new view results in 404 Page

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do something very simple and I seem to be missing something. I tried to scour the internet for results but haven't gotten anywhere so I was wondering if someone can please advise on this seemingly easy and straightforward task.

I have a working MVC Application and have created Models, Controllers, Views using the defaults (scaffolding).

Now I want to create a new view for one of my controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Blog.ToList());
        }
```

So I right click on Action Result and click Add View.
This gives me a dialog box where I specify a view name of "Test", I click "Create a Strongly Typed View" check box and select model class of Blog.
For scaffold template, I leave empty (note I have tried index without any good result)
Now I click the Add button.

As expected this creates a new view test.cshtml under Views/Blogs

Now when I begin without debugging and go to url: localhost:12341/Blog/Test

I get the following error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Blog/test

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Comment: I'm confused why you specified Visual Studio 2012, but yet your .net Framework version is 4.0?  The version of VS makes no difference, the important part is which framework version you're using.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a lot of issues with why it doesn't work. It is probably worth your while to look into ASP.NET MVC routing. For now, Mystere Man's solution might be a "quick fix" assuming you have everything else set up to their defaults.

In particular, when you tell your browser to go to `localhost:12341/Blog/Test` then it will (probably) look for a Controller called `BlogController` and then perform the `Test` action. In your case, your action is called `Index` so you would want to go to `localhost:12341/Blog/Index` (though you may be able to omit `Index` since it's the default action). Lastly, since your action is called `Index` then the `View()` function will automatically look for `Index.cshtml`. This is detailed somewhat in the msdn documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492930(v=vs.100).aspx

In particular:

> If the ViewName property is empty, the current action name is used in place of the ViewName property.

Answer (score 3):

Your action method is called Index, not Test.  If you want the url to be /Test, then you need to name the action method Test (there are other ways to do it, but this is the best way)

If you want to use the view Test, then you need to specify it in your View() method.

```
return View("Test", db.Blogs.ToList());
```

However, you will still need to use the Index url /Blogs/Index because your action method is Index.